# conditional checkboxs javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two checkboxes and have added conditions to enable and disable both checkboxes and input text based on selection.

My code as below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">messi</div>
  <div class="col2"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap messi">
    <input type="text" name="messi" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="sel_messi" aria-invalid="false">
    </span></div>
  <div class="col34"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap argentina"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="kra"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
    <input type="checkbox" name="argentina[]" value="argentina">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">argentina</span></span></span></span></div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">ronaldo</div>
  <div class="col2"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap ronaldo">
    <input type="text" name="ronaldo" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="sel_ronaldo" aria-invalid="false">
    </span></div>
  <div class="col34"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap portugal"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="unf"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
    <input type="checkbox" name="portugal[]" value="portugal">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">portugal</span></span></span></span></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  enable_cb6();
  $("span#kra> span > input[type='checkbox']").click(enable_cb6);

  $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);

});

function enable_cb6() {
  if (this.checked) {
  $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", true);

  } else {
  $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);

  }
}
/////
$(function() {
  enable_cb7();
  $("span#unf> span > input[type='checkbox']").click(enable_cb7);

  $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#kra input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);

});

function enable_cb7() {
  if (this.checked) {
  $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", true);

  } else {
  $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);

  }
}
```

**Live jsFiddle code:**

**[jsFiddle live code link here](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3kwcd1/)**

**What I want to do?**

By default, "messi" input text and "ronaldo" input text are freezed. When someone "checks" "argentina" checkbox, "messi" input text, "ronaldo" input text and "portugal" checkbox should be disabled.

When someone "unchecks" "argentina" checkbox, "messi" input text, "ronaldo" input text should be disabled and "portugal" checkbox should be enabled.

When someone "checks" "portugal" checkbox, "messi" input text, "ronaldo" input text should be enabled and "argentina" checkbox should be disabled.

So the user can see only the "argentina" checkbox and "portugal" checkbox and can check either.

I have tried to make it work, but have stuck up on conditions.

Comment: I would appreciate a reason for the downvote. I have not pasted a "code junk" but a part of code that I have tried and not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a strange requirement that the first checkbox disables both textboxes and the second checkbox enables both textboxes, but the question clearly says to do that, so...

You can implement this with *much* less JS as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  // save a reference to both text inputs, and disable them to start:
  var textboxes = $("#sel_messi,#sel_ronaldo").prop("disabled", true);
  // select both checkboxes, and bind a click handler to them, also saving
  // a reference to both
  var cbs = $("#kra,#unf").find("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    // set disable state of other checkbox according to this one's checked state:
    cbs.not(this).prop("disabled", this.checked);
    // set disable state of textboxes based on second checkbox's checked state:
    textboxes.prop("disabled", !cbs.get(1).checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">messi</div>
  <div class="col2"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap messi">
    <input type="text" name="messi" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="sel_messi" aria-invalid="false">
    </span></div>
  <div class="col34"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap argentina"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="kra"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
    <input type="checkbox" name="argentina[]" value="argentina">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">argentina</span></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">ronaldo</div>
  <div class="col2"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap ronaldo">
    <input type="text" name="ronaldo" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="sel_ronaldo" aria-invalid="false">
    </span></div>
  <div class="col34"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap portugal"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="unf"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
    <input type="checkbox" name="portugal[]" value="portugal">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">portugal</span></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq3kwcd1/3/

But as for what was wrong with your code: your `enable_cb7()` function was referencing `#unf` when it should've referenced `#kra`, and also in its `else` case it was enabling the textboxes when it should've been disabling them.

You don't need two document ready handlers, and you don't need to call `enable_cb6()` or `enable_cb7()` from the ready handler. You just need one ready handler to bind both checkbox click handlers and set the initial disabled state of the textboxes and second checkbox.

So here's a neater version of your functions that works:

```
$(function() {
  $("span#kra> span > input[type='checkbox']").click(enable_cb6);
  $("span#unf> span > input[type='checkbox']").click(enable_cb7);

  $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
});

function enable_cb6() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
  }
}

function enable_cb7() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#kra input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#kra input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq3kwcd1/2/

Comment: Brilliant .. It works perfectly .. Thank you so much :) +1 and answer accepted.

Comment: No problem. Note that after you accepted it I updated the answer to include a *much* shorter five-line solution.

Comment: I checked it and that one too is beautiful, just that mine one is a small part of an existing big system, hence I shall be sticking to it, but good to learn smart ways of doing. Shall keep that in mind for future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as like you desire , just removed the messy part and added clean conditions

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3kwcd1/1/)

```js
$("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);   $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
    
      $("span#kra> span > input[type='checkbox']").click(enable_cb6);   $("span#unf> span > input[type='checkbox']").click(enable_cb7);
    
      function enable_cb6() {
        if (this.checked) {
          $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", false);
          $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
          $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
          $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
          $("#unf input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
        }   }
    
      function enable_cb7() {
        if (this.checked) {
          $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", false);
          $("#kra input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
          $("#sel_messi").attr("disabled", true);
          $("#sel_ronaldo").attr("disabled", true);
          $("#kra input[type='checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
        }   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">messi</div>
  <div class="col2"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap messi"><input type="text" name="messi" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="sel_messi" aria-invalid="false"></span></div>
  <div class="col34"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap argentina"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="kra"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last"><input type="checkbox" name="argentina[]" value="argentina"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">argentina</span></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">ronaldo</div>
  <div class="col2"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap ronaldo"><input type="text" name="ronaldo" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="sel_ronaldo" aria-invalid="false"></span></div>
  <div class="col34"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap portugal"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="unf"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last"><input type="checkbox" name="portugal[]" value="portugal"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">portugal</span></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. +1 for the efforts